# How can I use select count (distinct x) in order to count two values in the same table and get the the two distinct values in my output?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I am trying to use count (distinct) in order to count the number of distinct values for two different values in the same table. The output I am trying to get should have both of the distinct values as two separate columns. I have been trying different methods but I keep on getting syntax errors. I am able to to count just one of the values without any problem, but I can not figure out the syntax for two.

For example, I can count one by executing:

```
select count(distinct origin) as distinctOrigin
from flights;
```

But I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
select count(distinct origin) as distinctOrigin and
select count(distinct dest) as distinctDestination
from flights;
```

And get two output values as two separate columns.

Comment: Would I use a join statement? I have not tried this because they are in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just have two expressions in the `select`?

```
select count(distinct origin) as distinctOrigin,
       count(distinct dest) as distinctDest
from flights ;
```

Comment: Yep, this works. I seriously thought I tried this syntax... Must have ignored the comma and tried sticking an and in there. Thanks!!